# Tagging git for snapshots using Maven

Tags: maven, nexus

We use the following command to release the current version.

```
mvn release:prepare release:perform
```

This command creates a tag in git that lets us know in the future which commit corresponds to a given released artifact.

When we want to generate a snapshot only and push it to Nexus, we use the below command, which pushes a timestamped snapshot to Nexus.

```
mvn deploy
```

Is there a way to tell Maven to create a git tag with the same snapshot name or even the snapshot timestamp just like the release plugin does?

Comment: The question is why tagging a SNAPSHOT because a SNAPSHOT is a moving target (apart from that SNAPSHOT's will be deleted by most of the repository managers after a time) so if you need something which can be referenced use a releas?...

Comment: @khmarbaise because we need to do the regression testing on the version in a test environment before releasing it, and also we need to keep these git tags and the timestamped snapshots only for a short duration. once the regression testing is completed, we will be able to say "this tag has passed the integration tests, and so this version can be released". please let me know if there is a better way to address this as I feel like I could be missing something better

Comment: If something is going of out development it's an release..If you need regression testing you don't have enough unit/integration tests in your software.. I would make simply a release deliver it to testing... If something comes back make a bug fix release on it...and so on... merge changes in your main back in between. That solves all problems related to that.